# publish failed because of Microsoft.OData.Client missing

Tags: publishing

the error message is:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Client, Version=7.5.2.21120, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

only this publish failed. others success.
My understanding is this dll should be loaded in runtime. what is the location of it?

Answer (score 5):

This is because most probably you reference `Microsoft.OData.Client` library in some event system, but you have not merged it with current DLL. Exception is self-explanatory. Some piece of your code cannot reference `Microsoft.OData.Client` library. By MSDN, it's not part of .NET framework, so you need to deploy it reference it additionally (either by merging it with your Event System into a single DLL using ILMerge or similar tool), or by (which is a worse-case scenario) adding it into a GAC.

Comment: I added this dll with the version to GAC. but the error is still there. I also added Microsoft.OData.Core and Microsoft.OData.Edm with the same version

Comment: have you added the correct version, with right name in GAC, or any other version. I ask because GAC is version specific.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it's correct version